# Using enum keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum and would like to use its keys to get its value.
I am instead getting `TS2538: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.` for the key `state['current']['civilStatus']`.

```
export enum ZivilstandForDTV {
    SINGLE = 'ledig',
    SINGLE_WITH_CHILDREN = 'ledig',
    MARRIED = 'verheiratet',
    CIVIL_UNION = 'in eingetragener Partnerschaft',
}

type keys = keyof typeof ZivilstandForDTV;
```

Here is where I would like to use the fetch the value:

```
{label: 'Aktuell Zivilstand', value:
 state['current'] ? ZivilstandForDTV[state['current']['civilStatus']] : ''},
```

I am not sure how to define the index type correctly.

Comment: `state['current']['civilStatus']` may be `undefined`. You will have to make sure first that it is not `undefined` before using it to index.

Comment: It's [perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question, but it should be posted as an answer and not as an edit to the question post.  Please move your solution out of the question and post it as its own answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution thanks to @TobiasS

```
{label: 'Aktuell Zivilstand', value: state['current']['civilStatus'] ? ZivilstandForDTV[state['current']['civilStatus']] : ''},
```